# Android OpenGL camera2 texture resolution

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera2

**Intro**

I'm using [CaptureRequest.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.Builder.html) and provide two surfaces as a target: a [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) for drawing GL and an [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html) ([getSurface()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html#getSurface())) for processing frame.

I set desired resolution 640x480 by setting [surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html#setDefaultBufferSize(int,%20int)) and by creating [ImageReader.newInstance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html#newInstance(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

**The problem**

It appears that [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) OpenGL texture is getting image that is of different aspect ration than 640x480 (4:3), more like 2560x1440 (16:9)([SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) occupying full screen, see **IMG 3**). It has to be noted that both phones have same resolution aspect ratio **16:9**. (Texture offset from the sides is left intentionally).

Below you can see **IMG 1** displayed on a monitor screen, and **IMG 2** and **IMG 3** are phone screen captures where current activity view is showing camera preview.

**The question**

How to correctly force [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) or [GLSurfaceView.Renderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html) to get specific (4:3 in this case) aspect ratio texture image from camera for arbitrary size View?

**Relevant**

It has to be noted that there is [an app](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/tree/master/android/tfmobile) that addresses issue, but for that [they change the view size](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/android/tfmobile/src/org/tensorflow/demo/AutoFitTextureView.java) to correspond to desired aspect ratio.

**See also**:

- [GitHub repo](https://github.com/aleksas/androidGlesCamera2).
- [Relevant source code](https://github.com/aleksas/androidGlesCamera2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gscoder/androidglescamera2/CameraHandler.java#L169-L185).
- [Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841619/android-camera2-capture-image-skewed?rq=1)
- [Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577299/android-camera-preview-stretched?rq=1)

**IMG 1** - Displayed source image:
[image]

**IMG 2** - Good aspect ratio ([Google Nexus 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_5) - Android 6.0.1):
[image]

**IMG 3** - Bad texture aspect ratio ([LG-D855](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_G3) - Android 5.0)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Fixed" the issue by updating LG phone to Android 6.0.

Comment: It's not a solution if you release your app to the world. So don't use Camera2 API if you support Android 5-7: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/issues/123