# Android Camera2, I aquire YUV image from ImageReader. U and V buffers have only one row(stride) data, the rest is zero

Tags: android, yuv, camera2

This is how I instantiate the ImageReader.

```
Size[] sizes = configs.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);

        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, null);

        Surface rgbCaptureSurface = mImageReader.getSurface();
        List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>();
        surfaces.add(rgbCaptureSurface);

        //surfaces.add(surface);

        mPreviewRequestBuilder
                = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        //mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(rgbCaptureSurface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {


            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                // The camera is already closed
                if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                    return;
                }

                // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                try {
                    // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);

                    // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                    //setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

                    // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                    mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                    mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                            mCaptureCallback, null);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Reading is done like this:

```
  public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Image image;
        while (true) {
            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

            if (image == null) return;


            Image.Plane Y = image.getPlanes()[0];
            Image.Plane U = image.getPlanes()[1];
            Image.Plane V = image.getPlanes()[2];

            int Yb = Y.getBuffer().remaining();
            int Ub = U.getBuffer().remaining();
            int Vb = V.getBuffer().remaining();

            byte[] data = new byte[Yb + Ub + Vb];


            Y.getBuffer().get(data, 0, Yb);
            U.getBuffer().get(data, Yb, Ub);
            V.getBuffer().get(data, Yb + Ub, Vb);
```

I tried several different ImageFormats. I'm testing on LG G3, API 21 and the problem occurs.On Nexus 4 I do not have the problem, API 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation is correct. API 21 does not properly support Camera2. This has been found by several people independently here on SO, see e.g. [Camera2 API21 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35997799/5148048)

So it is reasonable to start using Camera2 not before API22. It is not understandable why documentation hasn't been amended in the meantime.

Personally I am continuing to perform Camera2 studies, but I am still reluctant to use Camera2 in my app now. I first want to test it on many many devices first and for the near future I don't expect "Camera1" not being supported anymore by new devices.

Comment: Do you have any observation on how to fix the orientation of the image. I have this problem also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845245/image-data-from-android-camera2-api-flipped-squished-on-galaxy-s5

Comment: I have solved the the conversion YUV420_888 to RGB, see here http://stackoverflow.com/q/36212904/5148048. I am confident this works for many or even all devices. You need to set-up RenderScript, which is not so difficult.

Comment: Does the skew problem persist with render script?

Comment: No, the pictures are perfect. If you haven't set-up RenderScript here is a short manual: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31843987/5148048. In point 12 you take the rs-Code from the link above, put it into an empty file within the rs-Folder and name that file yuv420888.rs.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to API 23 and the same code worked fine. Also tested on API 22 and it also worked.

Same as : [Using Camera2 API with ImageReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350451/using-camera2-api-with-imagereader/38331912#38331912)